# How to customize a QDockWidget's QTabBar?

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget, qtabbar

I am talking about this :

[image]

How to get the `QTabBar` when my `QDockWidget`s are docked? I'd like to replace it with a customized one. The only thing I found for `QDockWidget` using a `QTabBar` was in the sources, a class named **`QDockAreaLayoutInfo`**. But it didn't help me that much...

Is it even possible to do something like this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't access this using public APIs. It's only in the last release or two that programmatically tabifying the dock widgets became possible. I'm not even sure dock widgets rely on `QTabBar`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is an alternate method.

Comment: Replacing this tab bar by a customized one. From what I saw in the source code, it is definitely a QTabBar (you can also see that by modifying the stylesheet)

Comment: Apologies: is there a specific behavior you'd like to achieve? Good to know about the tab bar, by the way. I'd wondered that but hadn't delved into the source far enough to see.

Comment: Not a specific behavior in fact, but just adding a picture on the left of the title would be great! And I don't think it is possible without retrieving the tab bar

Comment: AFAIU, your thinking is correct. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: Oh don't be sorry, glad to have someone interested at least :)